# reduction parallel loop in julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

We can use

```
c = @parallel (vcat) for i=1:10
          (i,i+1)
       end
```

But when I'm trying to use push!() instead of `vcat()` I'm getting some error. How can I use `push!()` in this parallel loop?

```
c = @parallel (push!) for i=1:10
     (c, (i,i+1))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating a bit on Dan's point; to see how the `parallel` macro works, see the difference between the following two invocations:

```julia
julia> @parallel print for i in 1:10
         (i,i+1)
       end
(1, 2)(2, 3)nothing(3, 4)nothing(4, 5)nothing(5, 6)nothing(6, 7)nothing(7, 8)nothing(8, 9)nothing(9, 10)nothing(10, 11)

julia> @parallel string for i in 1:10
         (i,i+1)
       end
"(1, 2)(2, 3)(3, 4)(4, 5)(5, 6)(6, 7)(7, 8)(8, 9)(9, 10)(10, 11)"
```

From the top one it should be clear what's going on. Each iteration produces an output. When it comes to using the specified function on those outputs, this is done in output pairs. Two first pair of outputs is fed to print, and *the result of the print operation* then becomes the first item in the next pair to be processed. Since the output is `nothing`, `print` prints nothing then (3,4). The result of this print statement is `nothing`, therefore the next pair to be printed is `nothing` and `(4,5)`, and so on until all elements are consumed. I.e. in terms of pseudocode, this is what's happening:

Step 1: state = print((1,2), (2,3));  # state becomes `nothing`
Step 2: state = print(state, (3,4));  # state becomes `nothing` again
Step 3: state = print(state, (4,5));  # and so forth

The reason string works as expected is because what's happening is the following steps:

Step 1:  state = string((1,2),(2,3));
Step 2:  state = string(state, (3,4));
Step 3:  state = string(state, (4,5);
etc

In general, the function you pass to the parallel macro should be something that takes *two inputs of the same type, and outputs an object of the same type*.

Therefore you cannot use `push!`, because this always uses two inputs of different types (one array, and one plain element), and outputs an array. Therefore you need to use `append!` instead, which fits the specification.

**Also note** that the order of outputs is not guaranteed. (here it happens to be in order because I only used 1 worker). If you want something where the order of operations matters, then you shouldn't use this construct. E.g., obviously in something like addition it doesn't matter, because addition is a completely associative operation; but if I used `string`, if outputs are processed in different order, then obviously you could end up with a different string than what you'd expect.

**EDIT - addressing benchmark between vcat / append! / indexed assignment**

I think the most efficient way to do this is in fact via normal indexing onto a preallocated array. But between `append!` and `vcat`, append will most certainly be faster as vcat always makes a copy (as I understand it).

Benchmarks:

```julia
function parallelWithVcat!( A::Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1} )
  A = @parallel vcat for i = 1:10000
    (i, i+1)
  end
end;

function parallelWithFunction!( A::Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1} )
  A = @parallel append! for i in 1:10000
    [(i, i+1)];
  end
end;

function parallelWithPreallocation!( A::Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1} )
  @parallel for i in 1:10000
    A[i] = (i, i+1);
  end
end;

A = Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1}(10000);

### first runs omitted, all benchmarks here are from 2nd runs ###
# first on a single worker:

@time for n in 1:100; parallelWithVcat!(A); end
#>  8.050429 seconds (24.65 M allocations: 75.341 GiB, 15.42% gc time)

@time for n in 1:100; parallelWithFunction!(A); end
#>  0.072325 seconds (1.01 M allocations: 141.846 MiB, 52.69% gc time)

@time for n in 1:100; parallelWithPreallocation!(A); end
#>  0.000387 seconds (4.21 k allocations: 234.750 KiB)

# now with true parallelism:
addprocs(10);

@time for n in 1:100; parallelWithVcat!(A); end
#>  1.177645 seconds (160.02 k allocations: 109.618 MiB, 0.75% gc time)

@time for n in 1:100; parallelWithFunction!(A); end
#>  0.060813 seconds (111.87 k allocations: 70.585 MiB, 3.91% gc time)

@time for n in 1:100; parallelWithPreallocation!(A); end
#>  0.058134 seconds (116.16 k allocations: 4.174 MiB)
```

If someone can suggest an even more efficient way, please do so!

Note in particular that the indexed assignment is much faster than the rest, such that it appears (for this example at least) that most of its computation in the parallel case appears to be lost on the parallelisation itself.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I make no claim that the above are correct summonings of the @parallel spell. I have not delved into the inner workings of the macro in detail to be able to claim otherwise. In particular, I am not aware which parts the macro causes to be processed remotely vs local (e.g. the assignment part). Caution is advised, ymmv, etc.</sub>

Comment: Is the running time and memory allocating for `append!` like `push` or `vcat`?

Comment: @ReD That's a good point. I've added benchmarks to answer this.

Comment: So `append!` is more efficient than `vcat` in both sequential and parallel way and also it's more efficient than `push` in sequential too. Is there something like `push` or `appened` that work like `hcat`? because they work like `vcat` and I'm looking for something that it's like hcat but more efficient.

Comment: Like I said above, preallocate an Array, then assign to it by index. (I haven't used `push!` anywhere above, not sure what you're referring to).

Answer (score 3):

The `@parallel` is somewhat similar to `foldl(op, itr)` in that it uses the first value of `itr` as an initial first parameter for `op`. `push!` lacks the required symmetry between the operands. Perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
julia> c = @parallel (append!) for i=1:10
            [(i,i+1)]
       end
```